# How to Apply Catalog Price Rule BY category

Tags: discount, catalog-price-rules

I want to apply discounts on a product by category. If product X is in multiple categories, then its discount should to be by individual category.

Example: product X is in category "men" and "accessories"

- If I navigate in men then it shows 10 % discount on that product.
- If I navigate accessories then it shows 20 % discount.

But in Magento its applying the same discount on both categories.

Is it possible to show different discounts for the same product?

Comment: you can apply catalog price rules based on category id using Promotions > catalog price rules. check these tutorials if you did't created a promotion rule http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/magento-catalog-price-rules/ and http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/catalog-price-rules i am still unclear about your question. please edit and explain what actually you want.

Comment: @BabyinMagento read question carefully

Comment: what i understood is , you assigned the same product to 2 different categories...... in category 1, its showing 10 %, in category 2 , its showing 20 %. is it ?

Comment: You can't do this with default Magento- it's essentially tricking your users depending on how you navigate the site. You'll need some custom development if this is something you absolutely have to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot give the same product for the same customer different prices only dependent on how the customer navigates to it.

Well, you can apply custom prices on the fly when the product is added to the cart but it won't affect the display in the listing, because this is always fetched from the price index.

But I have a solution to your problem: Create two different *bundle product* that contain only one selection (checkbox, required) with your actual simple product as only option, and use the "fixed price" setting for the bundle. This way you can specify different prices for both and the same simple product SKU gets bought. Then add one bundle to one category and the other to the other. You can make the simple product "not visible individually" so that it cannot be found in search.

If your product is already a complex product type (configurable or bundle) you have to duplicate it instead.